# changing the style of a single branch in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-qtree

How can I change the color and style (like dashed or dotted) of only one branch, say the one between parent and grand-parent of `a` and `b`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}        

\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={font=\huge},
level distance=1.1cm,sibling distance=.8cm, 
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (\tikzchildnode)}],
frontier/.style={distance from root=350pt} % Align leaf nodes

\Tree 
[
\edge node[near end,left] {branch};
[   
\edge node[near end, left] {};
[
\edge node[] {}; [.a ]
\edge node[] {}; [.b ]        
]        
\edge node[] {}; [.c ]
]
\edge node[near end,right] {};
[   
\edge node[] {}; [.d ]
\edge node[] {}; [.e ]
]
]

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already have `\edge` everywhere, it's simply a matter of doing e.g. `\edge [dashed,red] ..`

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}        

\begin{tikzpicture}[every tree node/.style={font=\huge},
level distance=1.1cm,sibling distance=.8cm, 
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- +(0,-8pt) -| (\tikzchildnode)}],
frontier/.style={distance from root=350pt} % Align leaf nodes

\Tree 
[
\edge [dashed,red] node[black,near end,left] {branch};
[   
\edge node[near end, left] {};
[
\edge node[] {}; [.a ]
\edge node[] {}; [.b ]        
]        
\edge node[] {}; [.c ]
]
\edge node[near end,right] {};
[   
\edge node[] {}; [.d ]
\edge node[] {}; [.e ]
]
]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I change the style for all the edges in a tikz tree? I tried adding `/.style={red, ultra thick}` to the line `edge from parent path= ...`, but it doesn't have any effects.

Comment: @havij Don't know. I'd have thought that `every edge/.style={..}` would work, but it didn't.